# How to change the master of a canvas once it's initializied?

Tags: python, tkinter

Example:

```
frame = Frame(master=None)
canvas = Canvas(master=None, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.config(master=frame)
```

But this returns an error:

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-master"

How can I change the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply is not possible to change the master of a widget, once its initialized.

Comment: Ah ok got it. I'll leave this open just in case, but if there really is no way I'll just mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @BrianZhang Hi, hopefully you understood that there is no way to re-parent a widget, would appreciate marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: alright, I've found that there is no point I need to do this, and I'd been structuring my project completely wrong.